# How to access the activity object in Android

Tags: java, android, client

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Client client = new Client();
    try {
        client.connect("192.168.1.10",5555);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

   public void displayServerAnswer(String answer){
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mainTextView);
        textView.setText(answer);
    }
...
```

Client.java

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Observable;


public class Client extends Observable implements Runnable {

  private Socket socket;
  private BufferedReader br;
  private PrintWriter pw;
  private boolean connected;
  private int port=5555; //default port
  private String hostName="localhost";//default host name

  public Client() {
        connected = false;
  }

  public void connect(String hostName, int port) throws IOException {
      if(!connected)
      {
         this.hostName = hostName;
         this.port = port;
         socket = new Socket(hostName,port);
         //get I/O from socket
         br = new BufferedReader(new         InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
         pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);

           connected = true;
         //initiate reading from server...
         Thread t = new Thread(this);
         t.start(); //will call run method of this class
      }
  }

  public void sendMessage(String msg) throws IOException
  {
        if(connected) {
            pw.println(msg);
      } else throw new IOException("Not connected to server");
  }

  public void run() {
       String msg = ""; //holds the msg recieved from server
       try {
          while(connected && (msg = br.readLine())!= null)
          {
             //In Here I want to call MainActivity.displayServerAnswer()

             //notify observers//
             this.setChanged();
//notify+send out recieved msg to Observers
                 this.notifyObservers(msg);
          }
       }
       catch(IOException ioe) { }
       finally { connected = false; }
  }

...
}
```

In the place I specified, I want to be able to display the server answer.
How can I get access to MainActivity instance that created client object, in order to call its method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an acvtivity reference to your client in either a constructor or a set accessor method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Client client = new Client(this);
    try {
        client.connect("192.168.1.10",5555);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And in your java object:

```
MainActivity activity;

public Client(MainActivity activity) {
    connected = false;
    this.activity = activity;
}
...

public void run() {
       String msg = ""; //holds the msg recieved from server
       try {
          while(connected && (msg = br.readLine())!= null)
          {
             //In Here I want to call MainActivity.displayServerAnswer()
             activity.displayServerAnswer();

             //notify observers//
             this.setChanged();
             //notify+send out recieved msg to Observers
             this.notifyObservers(msg);
          }
       }
       catch(IOException ioe) { }
       finally { connected = false; }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

@hopia answer is pretty good. you also can implement the `Listener Design pattern`

```
public class Client extends Observable implements Runnable {

    public interface ClientListener {
        public void onAction();
    }

    private ClientListener mListener;

    public Client(ClientListener listener) {
         mListener = listener;
    }

   public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ClientListener {

         @Override
         public void onAction(){
              ....do whatever you need
         }
   ...
   }
```

Comment: I like this more general solution which keeps the Client object independent of MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

How about passing the activity instance as an argument to the Client's constructor?

```
// MainActivity
Client client = new Client(this);

// Client
public Client(Activity activity) {
  this.activity = activity;
  connected = false;
}
```